# How to change the default VNC server

Tags: vnc

'When I installed my Raspberry Pi OS (bullseye), I went with the default RealVNC as a VNC server. It's giving my a lot of headaches right now and I'd like to try a different one, so I installed [KasmVNC](https://github.com/kasmtech/KasmVNC/releases). The install instructions say to start the server by running

```
vncserver
```

However, this starts RealVNC - so apparently, it's a generic command that refers to whatever VNC is installed. How can I make this command start KasmVNC instead (or launch Kasm in a differnet way...)?

Comment: What happens when you run `kasmvncserver-easy-start`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some programs have alternatives that you can manage with [`update-alternatives`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/dpkg/update-alternatives.1.en.html)

At installation time those programs add themselves to a list of possible executables. You can find out if KasmVNC did that by typing:

```
$ update-alternatives --list vncserver
```

If listed, you can then do:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config vncserver
```

If not listed, you can add KasmVNC to the alternatives (check the [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/dpkg/update-alternatives.1.en.html) for the meaning of each parameter):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install  /usr/bin/vncserver vncserver /path/to/binary/KasmVNC 1
```

And then select it from:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config vncserver
```

Comment: Thank you, here's what this does:
$ update-alternatives --config vncserver
/usr/bin/kasmvncserver
$ sudo update-alternatives --config vncserver
There is only one alternative in link group vncserver (providing /usr/bin/vncserver): /usr/bin/kasmvncserver
Nothing to configure.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/kasmvncserver because link group vncserver is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/bin/vncserver with a link

Comment: Weird. Did `--list` work? Maybe you didn't have alternatives to begin with. What is the ouput of `ls -l /usr/bin/vncserver`?

Comment: Yes, `--list` worked
`$ update-alternatives --list vncserver
/usr/bin/kasmvncserver`

`$ ls -l /usr/bin/vncserver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Aug  7 00:05 /usr/bin/vncserver -> /etc/alternatives/vncserver`

Comment: I tried this thing that I found in the man page now: `yes '' | update-alternatives --force --all` I'm not sure at all if it was a good idea because I forgot to add `vncserver`, so it updates all the alternatives. However, running `vncserver` now starts KasmVNC, so it worked.